# Breakout pandas column by days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there a simple way of repeating a value by date range in through pandas with a new column of each individual day in between?

input:

```
Start       End          Category
1/1/2010    1/4/2010         A
2/1/2010    2/3/2010         B
```

output:

```
Start       End          Category      Date
1/1/2010    1/4/2010         A         1/1/2010
1/1/2010    1/4/2010         A         1/2/2010
1/1/2010    1/4/2010         A         1/3/2010
1/1/2010    1/4/2010         A         1/4/2010
2/1/2010    2/3/2010         B         2/1/2010
2/1/2010    2/3/2010         B         2/2/2010
2/1/2010    2/3/2010         B         2/3/2010
```

Comment: Have you found a way that wasn't simple? Please share what you've tried.